# DataGridViewTextBoxColumn with joins

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I'm trying to make a Updateable `DataGridView` using a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.

This is my code:

```
var query = from u in context.User
join ur in context.UserRole on u.ID equals r.UserID
join r in context.Role on ur.RoleID.ToString() equals r.ID.ToString() 
select new
{u.ID,
u.Nick,
u.LastLogin, 
Role = ur == null ? String.Empty : r.Name
};
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ColID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ColNick = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ColLast = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColRole = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

ColID.DataPropertyName = "ID";
ColNick.DataPropertyName = "Nick";
ColLast.DataPropertyName = "LastLogin";
ColRole.DataPropertyName = "Role";
ColRole.DataSource = context.Role.ToList();
ColRole.ValueMember = "ID";

userDataGridView.Columns.Add(ColID);
userDataGridView.Columns.Add(ColNick);
userDataGridView.Columns.Add(ColLast);
userDataGridView.Columns.Add(ColRole);

userDataGridView.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

The data displays properly.  But the combobox does not make the dropdown effect. So I'm not able to change it and I get this error.

[image: DataViewGrid]

I find that the data could trigger this error so I check the database and I'm not missing any groups. The data matchs perfectly. Any ideas about how to solve this error?. Thanks.

Comment: Avoid posting images of errors - especially when it's not in English

Comment: You might get a better description if you handle the on data error event as it says. Without knowing exactly what is in your two datasets it is impossible to tell what is wrong.